# iOS - Map a root JSON array with ObjectMapper in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsarray

I use the library ObjectMapper to map json with my objects but I have some issues to map a root json Array.

This is the received json :

```
[
   {
       CustomerId = "A000015",
       ...
   },
   {
       CustomerId = "A000016",
       ...
   },
   {
       CustomerId = "A000017",
       ...
   }
]
```

This is my object

```
class Customer : Mappable
{
    var CustomerId : String? = nil

    class func newInstance(map: Map) -> Mappable? {
        return Customer()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        CustomerId   <- map["CustomerId"]
    }
}
```

I map the json in my controller with

```
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSArray

if (error != nil) {
    return completionHandler(nil, error)
} else {
    var customers = Mapper<Customer>().map(json)
}
```

But it doesn't work, I tried `Mapper<[Customer]>().map(json)` but it doesn't work too.
Finally I tried to create a new swift object CustomerList containing a Customer array but it doesn't work.

Do you have an idea of how to map json of a root array ?

Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if you're receiving an array, shouldn't the values be inside _brackets_ instead of _parentheses_  like this `[ {CustomerId = "A000015" }, {...} ]` ?

Comment: Yes, I think it is the encoding display of the println in XCode. When I use println it display that with parenthesis and semicolon. But on Postman it is with brackets and comma.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I finally solve my problem :

The mapping method in the controller should be

```
let json : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error)

if (error != nil) {
    return completionHandler(nil, error)
} else {
    var customer = Mapper<Customer>().mapArray(json)! //Swift 2
    var customer = Mapper<Customer>().mapArray(JSONArray: json)! //Swift 3
}
```

If it can help someone.

Answer (score 8):

#### Using `JSONObjectWithData(::)` with the correct conditional downcasting type

Your JSON is of type `[[String: AnyObject]]`. Therefore, with Swift 2, you can use `JSONObjectWithData(::)` with a conditional downcasting of type `[[String: AnyObject]]` in order to prevent using `NSArray` or `AnyObject!`:

```
do {
    if let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization
        .JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        /* perform your ObjectMapper's mapping operation here */
    } else {
        /* ... */
    }
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

---

#### Mapping to `Customer` using `mapArray(:)` method

The `ObjectMapper`'s `Mapper` class provides a method called `mapArray(:)` that has the following declaration:

> `public func mapArray(JSONArray: [[String : AnyObject]]) -> [N]?`

The `ObjectMapper` documentation states about it:

> Maps an array of JSON dictionary to an array of Mappable objects

Thus, your final code should look something like this:

```
do {
    if let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization
        .JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        let customerArray = Mapper<Customer>().mapArray(jsonArray)
        print(customerArray) // customerArray is of type [Customer]?
    } else {
        /* ... */
    }
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

---

#### Mapping to `Customer` using `map(:)` method

The `ObjectMapper`'s `Mapper` class provides a method called `map(:)` that has the following declaration:

> `func map(JSONDictionary: [String : AnyObject]) -> N?`

The `ObjectMapper` documentation states about it:

> Maps a JSON dictionary to an object that conforms to Mappable

As an alternative to the previous code, the following code shows how to map your JSON to `Customer` using `map(:)`:

```
do {
    if let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization
        .JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        for element in jsonArray {
            let customer = Mapper<Customer>().map(element)
            print(customer) // customer is of type Customer?
        }
    } else {
        /* ... */
    }
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is provided by [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper). Use the `responseArray()` convenience method:

```
Alamofire.request(endpoint).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[MyMappableClass]>) in

            if let result = response.result.value {
                // Customer array is here
            } else if let error = response.result.error {
                // Handle error
            } else {
                // Handle some other not networking error
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not Working - 
Value of type 'DataRequest' has no member 'responseArray'

Answer (score 2):

In the same situation in my recent Swift 3, able to solve to get object mapper present in Array as root.

First convert json string into a Object Using serialization.

```
let parsedMapperString = Mapper<Customer>.parseJSONString(JSONString: result) //result is string from json serializer
```

Then you can get Customer DTO from the MapSet of JSON dictionary to an array of Mappable objects.

```
let customerDto = Mapper<Customer>().mapSet(JSONArray: jsonParsed as! [[String : Any]])
```

Hope it helps. Thanks to @Nicolas who pushed me close to get solution.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to solve the problem of mapping a root array with generic object is creating a generic object that creates a list with the object inside the class implementation. Let's see an example of this kind of implementation below:

```
    Alamofire.request(REQ_URL_STRING, 
       method: REQ_METHOD(eg.: .GET), 
       parameters: REQ_PARAMS, 
       encoding: REQ_ENCODING, 
       headers: REQ_HEADERS).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<GenericResponseList<SingleElement>>) in
            //your code after serialization here
    }
```

In the code above you'll fill the uppercase variables with your own values. Check that the response return in the closure is a generic object DataResponse from Alamofire, and I did create another one called GenericResponseList. I put inner the "<  >" the type of the object that I'll get a list from the server. In my case it was a list of SingleElements.

Now, take a look in the implementation of the GenericResponseList below:

```
final class GenericResponseList<T: Mappable>: Mappable {

    var result: [T]?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        result <- map["result"]
    }
}
```

Take a look, I have an variable inside the class that is a list of the generic type I sent to this class.

```
var result: [T]?
```

So now, when you get you JSON it will convert it in a list of SingleElement.

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Not working for me  ObjectMapper failed to serialize response

Answer (score 1):

Convert array to json and back:

```
let json = shops.toJSONString()
let shops = Array<Shop>(JSONString: json)
```